# MySQL - Select when last entry before timestamp has specific value

Tags: mysql, select

I can find rows in a table where the last row has a specific value. However, I'm having a hard time finding them when I need to limit the max, or min, timestamp.

Let's say I have table 'people'.

```
id   name   value   date
a    last   jones   2018-04-03 01:00:00
a    last   smith   2018-04-03 03:03:03
a    last   johns   2018-04-04 02:02:02
b    last   johns   2018-04-03 12:12:12
b    last   smith   2018-04-04 03:03:03
c    last   smith   2018-04-03 11:11:11
c    last   johns   2018-04-03 17:17:17
c    last   jones   2018-04-05 01:01:01
```

I want to get the id's where the last row has name='last' and value='johns'

```
SELECT  distinct a.id
FROM    people a
left JOIN people b
   ON (a.id = b.id and a.name=b.name and a.date < b.date)
where b.date is null
  and a.name = 'last'
  and a.value = 'johns';
```

This gives me

```
id
--
a
```

Great. However, now I want to limit my search where date < '2018-04-04 00:00:00', which should return

```
id
--
b
c
```

I've tried adding a.date < and b.date < in the LEFT JOIN ON, tried adding a.date < to the WHERE but I'm not getting the expected results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, always post with `create table` statements and `insert` statements. You will get much more attention if people dont have to do a lot of work to be able to help you. After all, your time is not more valuable than everyone else time:

```
create table people 
( id char(1) not null
, name char(4) not null
, value varchar(20) not null
, ts timestamp not null);

insert into people (id, name, value, ts)
values ('a',    'last',   'jones',   '2018-04-03 01:00:00')
     , ('a',    'last',   'smith',   '2018-04-03 03:03:03')
     , ('a',    'last',   'johns',   '2018-04-04 02:02:02')
     , ('b',    'last',   'johns',   '2018-04-03 12:12:12')
     , ('b',    'last',   'smith',   '2018-04-04 03:03:03')
     , ('c',    'last',   'smith',   '2018-04-03 11:11:11')
     , ('c',    'last',   'johns',   '2018-04-03 17:17:17')
     , ('c',    'last',   'jones',   '2018-04-05 01:01:01');
```

It might be easier to grasp your query if you instead of a left join uses a `NOT EXISTS` predicate (rows where it does not exists a row after ..., i.e. last row):

```
select id 
from people a 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from people b 
    where a.id = b.id 
      and a.name=b.name 
      and a.ts < b.ts
) 
and a.name = 'last' 
and a.value = 'johns';
```

If you are interested in the situation before a certain point in time, add that predicate to both inner and outer select:

```
select id 
from people a 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from people b 
    where a.id = b.id 
      and a.name=b.name 
      and a.ts < b.ts
      and b.ts < '2018-04-04 00:00:00'
) 
and a.name = 'last' 
and a.value = 'johns'
and a.ts < '2018-04-04 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, instead of using an anti-join to filter out rows with dates earlier than the one you want, I'd rewrite the query to simply join to the maximum date for each ID:

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM people p
         INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(`date`) as last_date
                       FROM people
                      GROUP BY id
                    ) dt ON (p.id = dt.id AND p.`date` = dt.last_date)
 WHERE p.name = 'last'
   AND p.value = 'johns';
```

In this case, to limit based on the date, simply add the appropriate `WHERE` clause in the `dt` subquery:

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM people p
         INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(`date`) as last_date
                       FROM people
                      WHERE `date` < '2018-04-04 00:00:00'
                      GROUP BY id
                    ) dt ON (p.id = dt.id AND p.`date` = dt.last_date)
 WHERE p.name = 'last'
   AND p.value = 'johns';
```

Here's the [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uK2jFWyejmFmuZ8M1iqHuq/0) showing both versions of the query working.

I left out the `DISTINCT` as it was unnecessary with the data provided; if you may have multiple entries with the same `id`, `date`, `name`, and `value`, then you would want to put that back in.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE date < '...'
  AND name = 'last'
  AND value = 'Jones'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Will get you the previous row.  I'll let you build on that to do the rest of the task.

Meanwhile, you should rethink the use of EAV type schema.